# pycopg2 cursor with itersize returns one row at a time

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Having the following query

```py
con= psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=database,
    user=user,
    password=pwd,
    host=host,
    port=port
)
chunk_size = 100000 #500000 rows in the DB
cursor =  con.cursor(name='custom_cursor') 
cursor.itersize = chunk_size # chunk size
cursor.execute(query)
c=0
for row in cursor:
    print(c)
    print(f"Len_row: {len(row)}")
    c+=1
```

as far as I understand, `row` should consist of `chunk_size` elements, but `len(row)` is `1`. Since I have 500000 rows in the DB I would assume the loop to run 5 times, but `c` runs from 0 to number of rows and from 0 to 4 as assumed

Note: I'm running psycopg2==2.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is just how it works.  It gets then from the server 100000 at a time and gives them to you one at a time.

Comment: Then it makes sense why `list(cursor)` is soooo slow

Comment: I think it is missleading though in the documentation that it states it fetches `chunk_size` at a time and returns them to the user. One might assume that each element in `cursor` is `chunk_size` long